# TypeError: missing 1 required positional argument in call to super.__init__()

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm writing a program to find the volume of a cylinder using inheritance. However, I'm getting the following error, and I'm not sure how to resolve it:

```py
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'height'
```

Here is my code:

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self,radius,height):
        self.radius = radius
        self.height = height
    
class Cylinder(Circle):
    def __init__(self,radius,height):
        super().__init__(Circle)
        self.volume = 3.14 * (self.radius ** 2) * self.height
   def set_volume(self):
        print(self.volume)
    
radius = float(input("radius:"))
height = float(input("height:"))
cyl = Cylinder(radius,height)
print("Cylinder volume:", cyl.set.volume())
```

Comment: `super().__init__(Circle)` is calling `Circle.__init__`, which you've defined to take two arguments, `radius` and `height`. Currently, you are passing `Circle`, which doesn't make any sense, that is the class `Circle`, which is *not* what your `__init__` expects, leaving aside the missing `height` argument.

Comment: This really makes one wonder how you determine the height of a circle. Doesn't really seem like a good use of inheritance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to the `__init__` of the superclass isn't correct. You need to pass in the radius and height parameters explicitly, rather than passing in the name of the superclass.

```py
super().__init__(Circle)
```

should be

```py
super().__init__(radius, height)
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to you study a little bit OOP and relation between classes, because inheritance is not the case here and has no relation with the output error.

First things first and a cilynder shape is a 3d geometric form that can agregate a circle or implements another interface to a circle but is independent.

So this forms are **not properly a family** and should not have a link by inheritance.

See this [reference](https://realpython.com/inheritance-composition-python/) for more interesting things about agregation and comosition in software development.

I implement a funcional code for you, just a refactor.

```py
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self._radius = radius
        self._area = 3.14 * (self._radius ** 2)
    
    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius 

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self._area
    
class Cylinder:
    def __init__(self, radius, height, circle = None):
        self._height = height
        self._circle = circle if circle else Circle(radius)
        self._volume = self._circle.area * self._height

    @property
    def heigth(self):
        return self._height 

    @property
    def volume(self):
        return self._volume

    @property
    def area(self):
        return self._circle.area
    
# radius = float(input("radius:"))
# height = float(input("height:"))
radius = 5
height = 10

circle = Circle(radius)
cylinder = Cylinder(radius, height, circle = circle)

print("circle area:", circle.radius)
print("Cylinder area:", cylinder.area)
print("Cylinder height:", cylinder.heigth)
print("Cylinder volume:", cylinder.volume)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since height is a property associated with cylinder we will put `height` property in the `Cylinder` class and the base class `Circle` will only have `radius` property.
What you could better do have like below

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
        self.radius = radius
    
class Cylinder(Circle):
    def __init__(self, radius, height):
        super().__init__(radius)
        self.height = height # It makes sense to put height in the cyclinder here 
        self.volume = 3.14 * (self.radius ** 2) * self.height
   def set_volume(self):
        print(self.volume)
    
radius = float(input("radius:"))
height = float(input("height:"))
cyl = Cylinder(radius, height)
print("Cylinder volume:", cyl.set_volume())
```

Answer (score 0):

#The right code I am referring

```
class Circle:
    def __init__(self, radius):
    self.radius = radius

class Cylinder(Circle):
    def __init__(self, radius, height):
    super().__init__(radius)
    self.height = height 
    self.volume = 3.14 * (self.radius ** 2) * self.height
    def set_volume(self):
    print("Cylinder volume:",self.volume)

radius = float(input("radius:"))
height = float(input("height:"))
cyl = Cylinder(radius, height)
cyl.set_volume()
```